# Cant you specify an address of a pointer?

Tags: c

While this question is a bit easy, I really dont know what is the exact explanation about this.

```
char *ptr = 'a';
```

I know a char is not a string but isn't that obvious to store 'a' in the first index of the pointer?

Comment: Are you thinking of char *ptr = "a"; maybe?

Comment: @EnricoGranata Yes. I knew that already. Im not a beginner when it comes to C programming because i had 2 semesters of this. :) I jsut want to know why.

Comment: @PaulJabines Pilipina ang asawa ko.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment

```
char *ptr = 'a';
```

is equivalent to

```
char *ptr = 97; // This assumes ASCII encoding
```

While the assignment itself is valid, dereferencing this pointer is not valid.

If you would like to assign a pointer to point to something that has character `'a'` in it, you could use a string literal, an array initializer, or take a pointer of a single-character:

```
char *ptr = "a";  // String literal

char a[] = {'a'}; // Character array
char *ptr = a;

char a = 'a';     // Single character
char *ptr = &a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the address of a pointer.  Basically it is a pointer to a pointer.

```
char* ptr = "a";
char** addrOfPtr = &ptr;
```

Note that storing the 'a' in the first index of the pointer isn't really what is going on here.

The 'a' is located somewhere in the computer's ram.  The value stored in `ptr` is a number you can use to look up the ram location.  It is known as an "address" because when people described these locations they made an analogy to home street addresses.

So 'a' is not stored in the first index of the address, any more than you are stored in the first index of your street address.  You reside within the home at your street address, and the value for 'a' resides within the memory specified by the address value stored in `ptr`.

Note that this means the "pointer to a pointer", `addrOfPtr`, contains the address where the value within `ptr` resides.

---- Edit to drive the point home ----

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* ptr = "a";
  char** ptr_ptr = &ptr;
  printf("the value of ptr is '%s', and it is located at %p\n", ptr, &ptr);
  printf("the value of ptr_ptr is '%p', and it is located at %p\n", ptr_ptr, &ptr_ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Will print out a pointer's value and address.

```
the value of ptr is 'a', and it is located at 0x7ffff79642d8
the value of ptr_ptr is '0x7ffff79642d8', and it is located at 0x7ffff79642d0
```

You can see that the value of `ptr_ptr` is the address of `ptr`, showing that a pointer stores the *address* of a value, in such a way that the syntax is designed to make it easier to get the value **at that address** than the actual stored address.

Comment: THanks for very descriptive answer. :) No need to dig deep.

Comment: You're welcome, and I don't mind the "deep dive".  It's better to learn this right the first time, as pointers are going to play a central role in so many _yet to be experienced_ bugs in your upcoming C programs. :)  Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

A pointer must have an address assigned to it.  `'a'` is not an address.  It is a integer type with a value of `97`, assuming ASCII.  If you assign `ptr` the value `97` and try to dereference it you'll most likely get a segmentation fault because the address `97` does not exist.

`char *ptr = "a";` is correct because the compiler will store the characters `'a'` and `\0'` in contiguous memory, with the address of `'a'` being stored into `ptr`.

Comment: Does it mean that you cant specify an address for the pointer? Like, literally numbers(memory address).

Comment: Sure, you can. For example, you can do something like this: `char *ptr = (char *)97;`. You can do this regardless of whether `97` is a real address or not.